# Passing Variables in jQuery to Change a Dialog Title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to set up a dialog box, I want the name of the button pressed transferring into the dialog box, but I don't know how to do this.

So far I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#x").live('click', function(){
 var name = $(this).attr('name');  //want to pass this to the next jquery
 $('#dialog_box').dialog("open");
});
var input = $("#input");    
$("#dialog_box").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height:180,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Update": function(){
            alert(name);
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Also, how would I go about using the variable, once transferred to update the title of the dialog box (markup below)?

```
<div id="dialog_box" title="name variable here">
 <form id="dialog_form" name="dialog_form">
  <fieldset>
   <input type="text" name="input" id="input"/>
  </fieldset>
 </form>                
</div>
```

Any help appreciated   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `.live()` is deprecated, I suggest to use `.on()` and try `.data()` method

```
$(document).on('click', '#x', function(){
    $('#dialog_box').data('name', $(this).attr('name'));  //passed to dialog
    $('#dialog_box').dialog("open");
});
```

Calling inside dialog

```
  $("#dialog_box").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      resizable: false,
      height:180,
      width: 350,
      title: $(this).data('name'), //will set dialog title 
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Update": function(){
            alert($(this).data('name')); //should return input value
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely look into using the data() method more in future.  Every day is a school day  :)

Answer (score 3):

Please change the textbox id with suitable name.

try like this.

```
var titleValue=$("#input").val();
$( "#dialog_box" ).dialog({ title: titleValue });
```

or 
you can override the defaults like this

```
$("#dialog_box").dialog("option", "title", $('#titleText').val());
```

button click handler.

```
 $('#btnOpendialog').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#dialog_box").dialog('open');
     $("#dialog_box").dialog("option", "title", $('#titleText').val()); // to change the dialog title. 

 })
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qmtju/)

Comment: This set's the title value to the input.  The name variable will be set when a button is pressed (there are many each with different names generated from a mysql table).  Thanks for your input

Comment: Thanks for the demo, but you're not answering the question, @safarov has provided a working solution.  Thank you for you time.  :)