# Dynamically change Title of jquery dialog with is not getting cached data from select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a select dropdown in which whatever is selected I wish to display the name in the jquery dialog that pops up, problem I am having it that it seems to be caching/keeping the previous value and never changing it.

```
    var scenarioname = '';
    scenarioname = $('#FileUploadScenarioID option:selected').text();


    $('#dialog-module-add').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        draggable: true,
        height: 680,
        width: 720,
        title: scenarioname
    });
```

Yes, I see this article but putting that code in jsfiddle did not seem to give me what I am wanting  [Passing Variables in jQuery to Change a Dialog Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409658/passing-variables-in-jquery-to-change-a-dialog-title)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe:

```
$('#FileUploadScenarioID').on('change', function() {
    var title = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $('#dialog-module-add').dialog('option','title',title);
});
```

Comment: Works great!  Thx!                                                                                                                      var scenarioname = '';
scenarioname = $('#FileUploadScenarioID option:selected').text();

$('#FileUploadScenarioID').on('change', function () {
  scenarioname = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $('#dialog-module-add').dialog('option', 'title', scenarioname);
});

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps when you change the `option` within `select` it's not reassigning the new `scenarioname` value. What if you added an event handler for the select to reassign `scenarioname`

```
var scenarioname = '';
$("#FileUploadScenarioID").change(function () {
    $("#FileUploadScenarioID option:selected").each(function() {
        scenarioname = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(scenarioname);
});
```

Got something working here: http://jsfiddle.net/TEjqM/3/

Comment: I see that the jsfiddle did indeed work, just not sure why in my code it did not work.  I triple checked everything, I was skeptical about the other guys code but his did the trick.  Thanks.